# android rotate animation, make it fluid

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an ImageView that should rotate for 4 times. This is my xml of animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="3"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

but rotation is not fluid: there's a little delay from end of a rotation, and begin of next one. How can i fix it?

Comment: tried a custom Interpolaror ?

Comment: no, i only try with default interpolators.

Comment: so give it a try, it should help

Comment: or not, dont do that, just do one shot, no repeating with toDegree = 4*360

Comment: ok, your last solution works. but why default linear interpolator doesn't behave as i expect?

Comment: what you mean? linear interpolator works as expected

Comment: because i was expecting a fluid animation with linear interpolator :)

Comment: what you saw is a glitch in animation restarting, it has little to do with interpolators

Answer (score 0):

Try to rotate from 0 to 359. 0 and 360 is the same in that context.

Answer (score 0):

why not create an animation the usual way, and if you want it to rotate four times, then create a loop that iterates four times, and for each iteration, it calls the animation. You have to optimize your code so that are no visible drags.